# What is difference between Annotations, Marginalia, and Side notes?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am bit confused about the usage of the proper word (Annotations, Marginalia, and Side notes) in given sentence.

Example:  The revised version of my notes includes many useful ______ .

annotation: a note by way of explanation or comment added to a text or diagram.

side-note: a marginal note in a text.

marginalia: notes written in the margins of a text.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you tried looking these terms up in a dictionary, such as on dictionary.com? Or are those definitions not enough (why not?)? Unfortunately, questions that can be answered solely by using a standard dictionary are off topic on this site. So if you can explain why more than that is required...

Comment: @Cerberus yes, I looked them up online. All looks bit similar to me. I am confused.

Comment: They are all same.

Comment: side notes are informal, annotation are anything text or figures, and marginalia are any marks.

Comment: You could post the definitions that you found in the question (and explain which parts aren't clear to you or seem incomplete).

Comment: @Cerberus all this words are confusing

Comment: @VikramAditiya: Thanks for editing, it looks better now.

Comment: To most people, there is no difference.

To experienced printers, the positions they appear in make all the difference.

What did Google or your paper dictionaries leave unclear, please?

Answer (score 2):

Latin *margo* means "edge, border". The **margins** of a page are the white spaces at the edges of a page around the text. Because pages are rectangular, there are the side margins (left and right), the top or upper margin, and the bottom or lower margin (also called the *foot(er)*).

A **marginal** (plural **marginalia**) is something written in the margin of a page, usually a note. A note is a remark.

A **side note** is a note written to the side of a text, so it will be in the left or right margin of a page. This term is also used figuratively to mean any remark of lesser importance in speech.

An **annotation** is any note added to a text, so it can be anywhere in the margin (usually side notes or foot notes), or between the text (inline), or even hanging outside the page (such as in an attached codicil or post-it), or at the end of a chapter or of the book on separate pages (*end notes*), or even conceivably in a different booklet.

Typically, notes are placed as closely as possible to the text that they are relevant to, which can be a word, a sentence, a line, a paragraph. When the note is not inline, a little mark is usually placed immediately after the relevant text, such as a number, an asterisk, or a cross; this mark is then also added to the beginning of the note, so that one can easily find to which text a note refers.

So a marginal is usually a type of annotation, and a side note is usually a type of marginal. The only theoretical difference is that a marginal could in theory be something other than a note, such as a curse or a drawing; but, in your context, it is safe to assume that marginalia are notes.

In your examples, the meaning of *notes* would overlap with all of these three terms, so I don't really see them fit into the blank space in your example. Can you explain what it is you want to say, exactly?